# Can We Tell the Function Call Between Instances of Same Class is Recursive?

Tags: java, function, oop, recursion, methods

I had a quiz of the OOP Course that runs with Java language. We were asked to create a data structure for text file input like this:

```
A->ab|Ca|Ba
C->Bb|aB
B->a|b
```

to create an output like:

```
(ab|((a|b)b|a(a|b))a|(a|b)a)
```

input:

```
A->B|C
C->a|ba
B->b|ab
```

output:

```
((b|ab)|(a|ba))
```

Unfortunately, I can't fully share my solution due to Quiz paper but also we were asked to recursively print the full expansion of the ancestor node (node with head character "A"). I created a Node class to handle parent->children relationships and recursive print with toString method but I got no score from the recursive part of the quiz assignment and  I got feedback when I asked, that tells me, the solution is iterative and it is not recursive.

I couldn't accept that since the method is able to call another method that has the same instructions even if it is owned by a Node instance with a child role.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Node {
    private String head;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>> sets;

    Node(String c) {
        this.head = c;
        this.sets = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>>();
    }

    public String getHead() {
        return this.head;
    }

    public boolean hasChildren() {
        return sets.size() > 0;
    }

    // recursively (?) return proper output in context of nodes
    @Override public String toString() {
        if (!this.hasChildren())
            return this.getHead();
        String[] parts = new String[sets.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < sets.size(); i++) {
            String subs = "";
            ArrayList<Node> set = sets.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < set.size(); j++) {
                subs += set.get(j); // subs += ((Node) set.get(j)).toString() || The part that I think add recursive feature to method, it doesn't call itself but calls the same method of Node from a child
            }
            parts[i] = subs;

        }
        return "(" + String.join("|", parts) + ")";
    }
}
```

I need more opinions about it. Do you think the `toString` method is recursive? Which functions we cannot call recursive?

Edit:
There was also an instruction, "do not mind the recursive self calls", this means a case like: `B -> a|b|B`

From that sentence, I didn't mind the neither termination case nor input filtering so when you input a case like that your Node object takes an indirect call from either a child or itself.

Since there is a probability of receiving a recursive input, there will be a certain amount of ratio of probability upon toString function.

Comment: Recursive mean that you repeatedly apply the same function to a smaller input, until when a break condition occurs. Your toString() method clearly never calls itself, so by definition it is not recursive. Instead, it is iterating over the sets of the object in order to build the expansion. So, indeed, it is iterative and not recursive.

Comment: [This article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-recursion-and-iteration/) explains pretty much the difference between the two.  I suggest you to read it, it may help to clarify some ideas.

Comment: Are you sure that "sets" is an ArrayList of ArrayList of Nodes?  That, to me, appears to be incorrect.  I would think all you would need is an ArrayList of Nodes. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ First I want to thank you for your comment. Normally, It is clear to me that the usage of the recursion concept when exponent, Fibonacci, division, or other string operations happens in a non-OOP context. Yes, It technically never calls itself but it calls the same set of instructions from another Node object. That part confused me about the existence of a hybrid iterative-recursive concept.

Comment: @rBlue "sets" list is the list of elements separated by "|" in input. I needed it because when printing I had to be able to recreate "|" fractions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification on sets.  I see that is how you're solving the problem.  The loading of that collection would be a concern to me due to the fact that it could lead to NullPointerExceptions since the inner collection is not initialized when the Node is instantiated.  Due diligence would need to be extended to the loader, but that could be considered a business-rule leakage since it must have knowledge of the internals of Node.

Comment: @AbdulmelikSaylan Based upon your new edits to the question, I'm assuming "do not mind" is synonymous for "ignore". But it's unclear where it should be ignored; at input, or at printing the tree? My gut feeling would be related to only printing to prevent that self-node from becoming a cycle, mostly so the output will better reflect the input. But the input process that I presented is built in the reverse order so the child nodes can be connected; there is no "searching" or auto-connection, so the insertion of a cycle would have to be intentional.

Comment: In the past I've used a "collection" to keep track of all nodes that have been visited.  It makes the code a little more busy(ugly), but that technique can be used to prevent cycles at any depth, not just as a self-child.  I may try to add that to the answer that I've already provided to show how it would work with both the iterative answer and the recursive answer. Generally, in when a cycle is detected, we just ignore it, such as in processing ontologies.  But I'm thinking in these examples, it may be ideal to just show the node's name.

Comment: I was using a technique similar to yours to substitute. I was pooling the previous nodes the search and replace to connect nodes. Therefore, there was only one copy of each type of letter or symbol so probability was making the function recursive already according to my opinion. I mailed about it and indirect calls the function itself noticed but I got the response about the mismatch between the wanted solution and my solution. Probably you will see if you were able to read the quiz paper that the wanted solution is more like a recursive search on the input string as an argument.

Comment: My conclusion from the complaints is that the final decision has already been made about my solution. Although I couldn't find the mismatch between my solution and 
understanding of the paper, I gave up on my score.

Comment: Speaking directly about the code, allow me to provide feedback on what I see and feel about it, which may provide insight on how others may rate it.  If a student who I mentor would submit code like that, I would have them rewrite it because it’s overly complex and not clear. The results may be fine and correct, but my concerns are: future maintainers need to quickly understand what it's doing, and. overall simplicity is needed to reduce the potential for bugs now and in the future. The use of a nested ArrayList is not required to solve the problem, nor is it a pattern that I've seen before.

Comment: By gathering nodes in a new array of Strings, it appears like the code is unable to directly use the collections that contains the child nodes. Since the children must be gathered before they can be used, that "feels" like a design failure. Reviewing the code the first time, I did not understand the reasoning for the double layered ArrayLists, nor did I understand why there had to be a transitive use of a String array to process the child nodes.  These issues did present a serious concern.

Comment: The behavior of the code "appears" to be an iterative approach because the gathering of the children grabs the focus of the reviewer, and that could have strongly influenced your grade.  I would also conjecture that the amount of time to understand your code was limited, and therefore a decision was quickly made about what it was doing, without trying to better understand where the recursion actually is within the code.

Comment: I understand why you are calling your solution recursive, but at best it is implicitly recursive and not explicit, so therefore the recursion aspect could have been easily lost while trying to understand what the purpose of the String array was trying to accomplish.  My suggestion is to make the recursion more obvious by explicitly using the object's toString() function instead of just adding the objects to a String value, which will implicitly call toString().

Comment: Overall, I understand the results are correct, and recursion does exist implicitly, but there are too many issues related to style and good design that it would prevent me from giving it a high grade.  If creativity were a factor for the grade, then I would give you high marks for that, but I don’t think creativity was something they were looking for in the answers.

Comment: Well, grading is determined before the evaluation, and evaluation is constructed by units of evaluation where each unit has a certain amount of points also each unit is multiplied by a coefficient between 1 and 0. Recursive printing (40 points, base 100) was one of those units for which I got 0 for its coefficient. On the other hand quality of the code has 35 points to evaluate. I had limited time when I was building the solution so I couldn't go over it to make it more understandable with low complexity.

Comment: My concern was the zero coefficient of that evaluation unit because even if the function had a iterative look it was implicitly recursive. Although we can't call the function fully recursive it didn't deserve zero for it in my opinion.

Comment: The assignment and my solution had more background than I explain which is forbidden for me to share but I can say that rest of my classes and methods were for handling the text file and creating a single node tree with substitution operations on children. The node class had a head variable with the type of character because letter cases were used to distinguish terminal and non-terminal units If we consider a 2D array for children

Comment: Other than those, I want to thank you for your feedback. I believe we made the recursive concept on OOP clearer for people who are in the same confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure I do not fully understand your problem, but when reading over it, this is how I envision a workable solution.  Of course, the code is not there to load the data, but this Node class would represent the inputs from what I can tell.

So to answer your question, no, the `toString()` function is not recursive, but interative.

To show that this is a correct assumption, here are the classes which produces the following output.  Please note that I included two solutions: one which is iterative, and the other is recursive.  I kept the recursive solution as close to the `toString()` as possible so you can see the differences.

```
Iterative output:
((b|ab)|(a|ba))

Recursive output:
((b|ab)|(a|ba))
```

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Node
{
    private String head;
    private ArrayList<Node> sets;
    
    public Node( String head ) {
        super();
        
        this.head = head;
        this.sets = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        if ( getSets().size() > 0 ) {
            for ( Node set : getSets() )
            {
                if ( sb.length() > 0 ) {
                    sb.append( "|" );
                }
                sb.append( set.toString() );
            }
            
            sb.insert( 0, "(" );
            sb.append( ")" );
            
        }
        else {
            sb.append( getHead() );
        }
        
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String expandChildren() {
        return expandChildrenRecursive( this );
    }
    
    private String expandChildrenRecursive( Node node ) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        if ( node.getSets().size() > 0 ) {
            for ( Node set : node.getSets() )
            {
                if ( sb.length() > 0 ) {
                    sb.append( "|" );
                }
                sb.append( expandChildrenRecursive( set ) );
//              sb.append( set.toString() );
            }
            
            sb.insert( 0, "(" );
            sb.append( ")" );
            
        }
        else {
            sb.append( node.getHead() );
        }
        
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    public String getHead() {
        return head;
    }
    public void setHead( String head ) {
        this.head = head;
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> getSets() {
        return sets;
    }
    public void setSets( ArrayList<Node> sets ) {
        this.sets = sets;
    }
}
```

Now here is the class I used to build the objects so I can test it.

```java
public class NodeTest
{
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        
        Node nodeB = new Node("B");
        nodeB.getSets().add( new Node("b") );
        nodeB.getSets().add( new Node("ab") );
        
        Node nodeC = new Node("C");
        nodeC.getSets().add( new Node("a") );
        nodeC.getSets().add( new Node("ba") );
        
        Node nodeA = new Node("A");
        nodeA.getSets().add( nodeB );
        nodeA.getSets().add( nodeC );
                
        System.out.println( "Iterative output:" );
        System.out.println( nodeA.toString() );
        
        System.out.println( "\nRecursive output:" );
        System.out.println( nodeA.expandChildren() );
    }
}
```

Hopefully that does help to answer your question on how it is actually iterative and how a recursive solution is slightly different.

Comment: I should note that parsing the input text file would be a totally different challenge.  If you see how I accomplished building the dependencies in the class NodeTest, then you will notice that the text file would need to be loaded in reverse order. I would not be confident that the inputs would always be provided in the correct order, so the code would need to make adjustments to deal with sets that are out of order. Also cycles would not be valid either.

Comment: I just had an idea... let me modify my code example that I provided above, to provide a recursive solution.  That way, you can see, line for line, how they differ, which is not by much.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I think we are coming to the idea of making a new definition or making the definition clear because when I am creating the solution I had the idea of recursive as calling the exact same set of instructions with different parameters. I started to think the recursion concept is calling the function at the memory address of the function that recursion will occur. More clearer we can say, when we name the method of an object in Java "recursive" it must call the method that is in the same object.

Comment: I believe the example you gave supports this idea since the differences between function calls in your iterative and recursive methods are the basicly the parent objects (instances).

Comment: Yeah, to better clarify the recursive process: The recursive function call, repeatedly calls the same function, within the same instance, with different values for the Node parameter.  The iterative calls functions by the same name, but exists in the difference instantiations of each Node object.  Your example is simple in the reasoning that it can use either process with just changing one line of code.

Comment: @AbdulmelikSaylan Something to consider is that perhaps it's not ideal to think in terms of memory addresses of the functions that are being ran. There are numerous java runtime environments with many different optimizers.  Therefore it is possible that given the same Java class object, it may compile differently in different VMs due to the optimizers for that platform. I suspect most functions, even running through different object instantiations, could actually use the same memory addressed function, but I won't place any bets that it will be true on 100% of all java implementations.

Comment: You are right about the memory locations. Even if the Garbage Collector is considered, probably there will be some offset changes that may lead to the location change of the "recursive" function on the runtime.

Comment: @r Blue I don't know did you also think about a recursive input so I added more details about it to the description.